# What kind of prose style do most people like?

Tags: style

What kind of prose style draws in and delights the most people?

Comment: What genre are you writing? Who is your target audience?

Comment: Also, the question in the title is now different from the (edited) question in the body - are you asking what style appeals to *most people*, or what style appeals to *the most people*? (I mean, I think the answer to the former is 'there is no such style', whereas the latter may at least be answerable).

Answer (score 3):

### You can find a little bit of everything anywhere you look

If you do some research you'll find that many authors have used many different types of prose. I would suggest to do what you think would be the best prose to use for your specific project and you might be able to find an audience that is attracted to that same kind of prose. Or perhaps try to think about the audience when you are writing:

> What is it that I like?
> What would others like to see?
> How can I convey my stories in a way that is enticing?

These are a few questions you should ask yourself. Wait until you are ready to think about getting published and then consider the pros and cons of each possibility. With everything laid out in front of you, you'll be able to decide which course of action is best for you.